# PHP & MySQL - How to count visits by day

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I got a table named #__products_visits which records visits. Its structure is:

```
id
product_id
product_name
date
```

The counter script inserts a record while visiting. So, each row stands for a single visit at the database. Now, I wanna count number of visits by day and grab the number of visits by day. It's a Joomla! component, so the query better to be in Joomla! class.

The WHERE condition switcher which limits a bit:

```
$date_range = $_REQUEST['date'];

switch($date_range) {
    case 1:
    $scope = ' >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)';
        break;
    case 2:
    $scope = ' >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)';
        break;
    case 3:
    $scope = ' >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)';
        break;
    case 4:
    $scope = ' >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 365 DAY)';
        break;
    case 5:
    $scope = ' <= CURDATE()';
        break;
    default:
    $scope = ' >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)';
    break;
}
```

The select function I got so far:

```
// Count cart rows
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query
    ->select('*')
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__product_visits'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('date') . $scope);
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
// And here is where I've been stopped :-)
```

Comment: That's nice. What is your question here?

Comment: I need number of visits by day. E.g. 2017-01-01 2 visits,  2017-01-02 5 visits and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I figured it by user3741598's help is:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query
    ->select('date_format(`date`,"%Y,%m,%d") as DateVisited, COUNT(*) as row')
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__product_visits'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('date') . $scope)
    ->group($db->quoteName('DateVisited'));
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

and then I extracted the number of groups by a `foreach` from:

```
$x = $result->DateVisited;
```

and number of visits for each group by:

```
$y = $result->row;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your 'date' is really a date type variable this works - no clue what you're doing with the INTERVALS

```
SELECT date_format(`date`,'%Y-%m-%d') as DateVisited, count(*) from #__products_visits group by DateVisited
```

Comment: Thank you. My case is a bit complicated. I need generate the result for various duration regarding to the user select. It's the reason why I need the INTERVAL. The other matter I've to point to is I need 2 parameters for each day which has visit record(s); one, the date and two the number of visitors. As more description, I need to find how many visits each day has. Also, the date field is timestamp type.

Comment: It worked with some modifications. Now, please explain how can I get the date and number of rows for each record. In my table there are 3 days recorded, having visits and using your query, I could group the result by day. Now, I need the day and the number of visits (rows) for each of these 3 days. Thank you.

Comment: foreach($results as $result) { $x = $result->DateVisited; } returns the days. But how to find number of records for each day?